# A variant of the Euler product formula?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, euler-product

Does the following limit make sense? $\prod_{2 \leq p \leq n} (1-\frac{1}{p})\ln n \rightarrow 1,$ as $n \rightarrow \infty. $

Comment: Actually, [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) says the limit is $e^{-\gamma}\approx0.56\dots$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. (Also, this would be analytic number theory more than elementary number theory.)

Comment: @runway44 Thanks for answering.